# Building v8 from source on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, v8

How can one build `v8` from source on most recent Centos 7?

I tried, but `ninja` build always fails right away with "centos /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found" message.

Plus, dependency installer script tells that Centos platform is not supported.

So, is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is due a not compatible C compiler, try compiling a newer GCC. On CentOS 7:

```sh
sudo yum install bzip2
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-8.3.0/gcc-8.3.0.tar.gz
tar zxf gcc-8.3.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-8.3.0/
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
make
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64

echo "/usr/local/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc-8.3.0.x86_64.conf
ldconfig
```

(From their [wiki](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/wiki/Installing-on-CentOS-7-x64---PHP-7.3))

Answer (score -1):

You can try using docker to build V8.
See https://github.com/gengjiawen/v8-build.

Comment: That's for Ubuntu. I need CentOS 7.

Comment: You can run docker on CentOS, the Base Image doesn't matter.

Comment: That really doesn't work. V8 built in docker container with ubuntu 20.04 will not work on the centos 7.

Comment: What problem do you run into ? The build v8 are just binaries.